# Applist upgrade available on Cydia?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

Can someone tell me what this is ?? Can I remove it ?

It says : Allows developers to query the list of installed apps and provide a preference pane based on that information

*update* This is given in the the app's info.

```
Applist
1.4.2
Author Ran Petrich
Allows developers to query the list of installed apps and
provide a preference pane based on that information
Exports depslayidentifier, displayname, icone and smallicon
via a remote messaging center that its easy to write a prefs pane 
that presents a list of apps.
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with Activator, and maybe removing this will delete Activator as a whole.

I don want developers scooping around my installed apps...But  what happens if I remove it ?

*edit*

Haven't found anything about it yet .. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Can you add a little more information? Where did this statement come from?

Comment: updated the content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applist is a small code library that allows jailbreak app developers to get limited information about the apps that you have installed. Ryan Petrich is a reputable developer, and many popular jailbreak apps use this library. To name a couple, Activator and SBSettings use it. All jailbreak apps have access to everything on your device, so if you're worried about privacy, I'd suggest restoring your device to factory settings. Applist is a dependency to these apps, so if you uninstall it, it'll uninstall them, too. Applist is harmless, so just keep it.